# Deleting duplicates in groups A/B

Tags: pandas, dataframe, function, duplicates, ab-testing

I'm conducting an A/B test and looking for an effective way to delete duplicate users ID's (**visitorId** column) that appear in both groups: the experiment and the control.

Here is an example:

| visitorId | date | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **4256040402** | **2019-08-31** | **A** |
| **4256040402** | **2019-08-31** | **B** |
| 4256040402 | 2019-08-27 | A |
| 4256040402 | 2019-08-20 | B |

And the desired result:

| visitorId | date | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **4256040402** | **2019-08-31** | **A** |
| 4256040402 | 2019-08-27 | A |
| 4256040402 | 2019-08-20 | B |

I'm looking for an efficient way that takes into account the date (**date** column) and deletes duplicates but on the condition that it takes place in both groups and on the same day.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `drop_duplicates(subset=['visitorId', 'date'])`

```
print(df)

    visitorId        date group
0  4256040402  2019-08-31     A
1  4256040402  2019-08-31     B
2  4256040402  2019-08-27     A
3  4256040402  2019-08-20     B

df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['visitorId', 'date'])

print(df)

    visitorId        date group
0  4256040402  2019-08-31     A
2  4256040402  2019-08-27     A
3  4256040402  2019-08-20     B
```